# JQuery callback handling

Tags: jquery

I am implementing a plugin in my site, I have kept the required php and JS files on my server.  But I couldn't figure out how to handle the JQuery callbacks mentioned here - http://goo.gl/I6CFPZ

Kindly demonstrate with an example, how to retrieve the array of results. Your feedback will be appreciated.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(window).load(function() {

            polljoy({
                endPoint : 'connect.php'
            }, function PJPollIsReady(polls){
                console.log(polljoy('show'));   
            });


        });
    </script>
```

Comment: @NoLifeKing sample code updated!

Comment: If you move the callback-code outside the `polljoy`-block, does it work? (I can't really set this up at the moment to test). So that the `PJPollIsReady` is after the semicolon of the `polljoy`-command.

Comment: Nope! It gives error, undefined polls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample for `PJPollDidShow` event

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {

    polljoy({
        endPoint : 'connect.php',
        PJPollDidShow: function(poll){
           //Here is the callback for the PJPollDidShow event
        }
    });
});
```